# How to format pdf generated from repeater control in asp.net using iTextSharp

Tags: c#

I am exporting data from my repeater control to pdf using iTextSharp. The pdf generated is in the tabular format with following heading columns:-

Sr No   Product  Installation-date  Customer    Mechanic

Now I want to modify the height and width of these columns in pdf.
Pls help how to do this using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've used CSS for formatting iTextSharp PDF output. It has limited support for CSS but, as a web developer, I've found simplifying the design of the PDF and using the CSS features it does support was much easier than managing layout and formatting programmatically. To do this you must use iTextSharp's [XMLWorkerHelper](http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/XMLWorkerHelper.html) which offers support for parsing and rendering XHTML, where the simplest typical usage looks like:

```
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(PdfWriter, PdfDocument, TextReader)
```

You can also specify a separate CSS file via an [overload of this ParseXHtml](http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/XMLWorkerHelper.html#parseXHtml(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,%20com.itextpdf.text.Document,%20java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.InputStream))

Here's a list of supported CSS in iTextSharp http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm. You can see that both width and height are supported for table cells (<td>)

So you could add some classes to your table cells in your repeater item template then prepend some of your own CSS to the response output. I assume you are changing response headers to convert your repeater to PDF output, you use the typical usage above passing in the response as the third parameter.